# Python List Repeating Last Element For Whole List

Tags: python, list, poker

I am writing a python program just to make a simple poker game. I just want to become familiar with the Python language. I know my method of writing the python code isn't exactly Pythonic but really I'm just trying to figure out why my list is appending the last object repeatedly to each space in the List. As I am appending, the list has the correct values but after it just appends the last object repeatedly. I've spent about two days trying to figure it out and I'm sure it's just something I'm overlooking with the language. Any help would be appreciated. Here is the code:

```
class Card(object):
    suit = ""
    value = ""

    def __init__(self, suit, value):
        Card.suit=suit
        Card.value=value

def createDeck():

    suit = ["DIAMONDS", "HEARTS", "CLUBS","SPADES"]
    value = ["ACE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR", "FIVE", 
         "SIX", "SEVEN", "EIGHT", "NINE", "TEN", 
         "JACK", "QUEEN", "KING"]
    Deck = []

    for i in range(4):
        for j in range(13):
            card = Card(suit[i],value[j])
            Deck.append(card)
            print(Deck[i].value, "OF", Deck[i].suit)

    displayDeck(Deck)

def displayDeck(Deck = [], *args):
    for i in range(len(Deck)):
        print(Deck[i].value, " OF ", Deck[i].suit)
```

This is the Output I get, it's shortened for brevity:
    C:\Users\root\Desktop>py Poker.py

```
ACE OF DIAMONDS

-All Cards Through-

KING OF SPADES

KING OF SPADES

KING OF SPADES

KING OF SPADES

KING OF SPADES
etc. Until The list is filled (52 spots)
```

Comment: Look at the `print` statement in `createDeck`; you are executing the same statement 13 times for each suit.

Comment: `Card.suit=suit` - where did you get the idea that that's how you set your instance attributes?

Answer (score 2):

In your `Card.__init__`-method you set class attributes instead if instance attributes. So every Card instance has the same attributes, the last one set (King Of Spades). So, set instance attributes with `self.`:

```
class Card(object):
    def __init__(self, suit, value):
        self.suit = suit
        self.value = value
```

So one usage of class attributes would be the constants of suit and value names:

```
class Card(object):
    SUITS = ["DIAMONDS", "HEARTS", "CLUBS","SPADES"]
    VALUES = ["ACE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR", "FIVE", 
        "SIX", "SEVEN", "EIGHT", "NINE", "TEN", 
        "JACK", "QUEEN", "KING"]

    def __init__(self, suit, value):
        self.suit = suit
        self.value = value

def create_deck():
    deck = []
    for suit in Card.SUITS:
        for value in Card.VALUES:
            card = Card(suit,value)
            deck.append(card)
            print(card.value, "OF", card.suit)
    return deck

def display_deck(deck):
    for card in deck:
        print(card.value, " OF ", card.suit)

deck = create_deck()
display_deck(deck)
```

Comment: typo in object naem `Card` in `for value in Cards.VALUES:`. Also, I agree with this method, cleaner to keep that stuff in the `Card` class

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this

```
    def __init__(self, suit, value):
       self.suit=suit
       self.value=value
```

This is how you properly set suit and value to Card object.

```
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(13):
        card = Card(suit[i],value[j])
        Deck.append(card)
displayDeck(Deck)
```

I deleted the print statement inside the loops.
Now the output is:

```
('ACE', ' OF ', 'DIAMONDS')
('TWO', ' OF ', 'DIAMONDS')
('THREE', ' OF ', 'DIAMONDS')
('FOUR', ' OF ', 'DIAMONDS')
('FIVE', ' OF ', 'DIAMONDS')
('SIX', ' OF ', 'DIAMONDS')
('SEVEN', ' OF ', 'DIAMONDS')
('EIGHT', ' OF ', 'DIAMONDS')
('NINE', ' OF ', 'DIAMONDS')
('TEN', ' OF ', 'DIAMONDS')
('JACK', ' OF ', 'DIAMONDS')
('QUEEN', ' OF ', 'DIAMONDS')
('KING', ' OF ', 'DIAMONDS')
('ACE', ' OF ', 'HEARTS')
('TWO', ' OF ', 'HEARTS')
('THREE', ' OF ', 'HEARTS')
('FOUR', ' OF ', 'HEARTS')
('FIVE', ' OF ', 'HEARTS')
('SIX', ' OF ', 'HEARTS')
('SEVEN', ' OF ', 'HEARTS')
('EIGHT', ' OF ', 'HEARTS')
('NINE', ' OF ', 'HEARTS')
('TEN', ' OF ', 'HEARTS')
('JACK', ' OF ', 'HEARTS')
('QUEEN', ' OF ', 'HEARTS')
('KING', ' OF ', 'HEARTS')
('ACE', ' OF ', 'CLUBS')
('TWO', ' OF ', 'CLUBS')
('THREE', ' OF ', 'CLUBS')
('FOUR', ' OF ', 'CLUBS')
('FIVE', ' OF ', 'CLUBS')
('SIX', ' OF ', 'CLUBS')
('SEVEN', ' OF ', 'CLUBS')
('EIGHT', ' OF ', 'CLUBS')
('NINE', ' OF ', 'CLUBS')
('TEN', ' OF ', 'CLUBS')
('JACK', ' OF ', 'CLUBS')
('QUEEN', ' OF ', 'CLUBS')
('KING', ' OF ', 'CLUBS')
('ACE', ' OF ', 'SPADES')
('TWO', ' OF ', 'SPADES')
('THREE', ' OF ', 'SPADES')
('FOUR', ' OF ', 'SPADES')
('FIVE', ' OF ', 'SPADES')
('SIX', ' OF ', 'SPADES')
('SEVEN', ' OF ', 'SPADES')
('EIGHT', ' OF ', 'SPADES')
('NINE', ' OF ', 'SPADES')
('TEN', ' OF ', 'SPADES')
('JACK', ' OF ', 'SPADES')
('QUEEN', ' OF ', 'SPADES')
('KING', ' OF ', 'SPADES')
[Finished in 0.3s]
```

Comment: But you don't define `displayDeck` anywhere. Also not really neccessary to write a function for something that takes two lines. Or one line even.

Comment: It is defined by the question's author. I just showed the changed parts.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate Rockybilly's answer, your `Card` class is defining two *class* attributes, `suit` and `value`. Every instance of your `Card` class shares these two values, meaning if you change it in one instance, it is changed in all instances. That's what's happening currently in your `Card.__init__` method when you do something like `Card.suit = suit`. You're modifying the suit for *all* `Card`s you've ever created. In your case, the King of Spades is the last card you create, so its suit and value is the one that gets set for all 52 cards you've created.

What you want to do is treat `suit` and `value` as *instance* values, meaning you refer to them within your class via `self`. Furthermore, you don't need to set their values at the class level (i.e., right below the `class Card` line). Instead, you just initialize them within your `__init__` method. Try changing your `Card` class to this:

```
class Card( object ):
    def __init__( self, suit, value ):
        self.suit = suit
        self.value = value
```

Comment: Thanks, I was worried about failing to use the exact terminology. Thats why my explanation was brief.

Comment: Thank you so much guys, I knew it was something I overlooked. I thought you could just use the object name in the constructor. It works like a charm now! Again thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can fix your `Card` class like this:

```
class Card(object):
    def __init__(self, suit = None, value = None):
        self.suit=suit
        self.value=value
```

This will solve your problem of the *last* card being displayed a bunch of times, because you are no longer constantly modifying the same `Card` object. But after that fix, you would have run into another problem because of your print statment. It's because on each loop of `j`, you are using the `i`th card in the deck, but `i` has not been incrememnted until `j` has increased by `13`. This would have been better:

```
current = 0
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(13):
        card = Card(suit[i],value[j])
        Deck.append(card)
        print(Deck[current].value, "OF", Deck[current].suit)
        current = += 1
```

But obviously is messy. You want:

```
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(13):
        card = Card(suit[i],value[j])
        Deck.append(card)
display_deck(Deck)
```

Comment: `i*j`? that don't fix the problem, better do `print(card.value, "OF", card.suit)`

Comment: Sorry, it should have been `i*(j+1)`. Yes, this will fix the problem. Its the same way you find a item index given a column and row number. But i still think the second option is a better choice

Comment: Nevermind, I changed it again. Its easier to declare a new counter variable than deal with `i` and `j` when either of them `= 0`