# Python List repeating the last element inserted for whole list

Tags: python, neural-network

I'm working around some neural network code. I've wrote my own neuron class, that could be find [here](https://github.com/abreufernandof/NeuralNets/blob/master/Neuron.py). Now, I'm writing the Brain Class, that should sumarize most of code used in a NN. In this class, self.Real_Outputs collects all the outputs and put it into a list to be used after.

I'm boiling my brain to find out why  when I add an element in self.Real_Outputs the whole list receive this value. I find [here in this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34440235/python-list-repeating-last-element-for-whole-list) a discussion similar to mine, but, in my case i've already used 'self' statement. Could you guys help me on that?

class Brain:

```
def __init__(self, training_set, desired_outputs, bias, learning_tax):
    self.Training_Set = training_set
    self.Desired_Outputs = desired_outputs
    self.Bias = bias
    self.Learning_Tax = learning_tax
    self.Hidden_Layer = []
    self.Hidden_Layer_Outputs = []
    self.Hidden_Layer_Errors = []
    self.Output_Layer = []
    self.Output_Layer_Outputs = []
    self.Output_Layer_Errors = []
    self.Real_Outputs = [0 for x in self.Desired_Outputs]

def set_hidden_layers(self, number_of_layers, number_of_neurons, activation_function):
    self.Hidden_Layer = [[Neuron.Neuron(len(self.Training_Set[0]), activation_function, 1, self.Bias)
                         for x in range(number_of_neurons)]
                         for y in range(number_of_layers)]

    self.Hidden_Layer_Outputs = [[0 for x in range(number_of_neurons)]
                                 for y in range(number_of_layers)]

    self.Hidden_Layer_Errors = [[0 for x in range(number_of_neurons)]
                                for y in range(number_of_layers)]

def set_output_layer(self, number_of_neurons, activation_function):
    self.Output_Layer = [Neuron.Neuron(len(self.Hidden_Layer[0]), activation_function, 0, self.Bias)
                         for x in range(number_of_neurons)]

    self.Output_Layer_Outputs = [0 for x in range(number_of_neurons)]

    self.Output_Layer_Errors = [0 for x in range(number_of_neurons)]

def start_converging(self):
        j=0
        while j < 10:

            # Here we're coming inside the training set. If was the n-th time
            # you pass here, it's the n-th iteration over the Training Set.
            # 'a' represents the Training Set index

            for a in range(len(self.Training_Set)):

                # Here we're running over the hidden layers
                # 'b' represent the layer index

                for b in range(len(self.Hidden_Layer)):

                    # Here we're running over the neurons in the layers
                    # 'c' represents the neuron index

                    for c in range(len(self.Hidden_Layer[b])):
                        if b == 0:
                            self.Hidden_Layer[b][c].initialize_inputs(self.Training_Set[a])
                            self.Hidden_Layer[b][c].get_sum()
                            self.Hidden_Layer_Outputs[b][c] = self.Hidden_Layer[b][c].get_output()
                        else:
                            self.Hidden_Layer[b][c].initialize_inputs(self.Hidden_Layer_Outputs[b-1])
                            self.Hidden_Layer[b][c].get_sum()
                            self.Hidden_Layer_Outputs[b][c] = self.Hidden_Layer[b][c].get_output()

                # Here we're running over the output layer
                # 'd' represents the neuron index

                for d in range(len(self.Output_Layer)):
                    self.Output_Layer[d].initialize_inputs(self.Hidden_Layer_Outputs[-1])
                    self.Output_Layer[d].get_sum()
                    self.Output_Layer_Outputs[d] = self.Output_Layer[d].get_output()
                    self.Output_Layer_Errors[d] = self.Output_Layer[d].get_error(0, self.Desired_Outputs[a])
                    self.Output_Layer[d].update_weights(0, self.Learning_Tax)

                self.Real_Outputs[a] = self.Output_Layer_Outputs

                # We're updating the hidden layers now. Notice that we should pass backwards, from
                # last to first, so, we're using [-(e+1)] indexes.
                # '[-(e+1)]' represents the layers index.

                for e in range(len(self.Hidden_Layer)):
                    for f in range(len(self.Hidden_Layer[-(e+1)])):
                        if e == 0:
                            self.Hidden_Layer_Errors[-(e + 1)][-(f + 1)] = self.Hidden_Layer[-(e + 1)][-(f + 1)].get_error(0, self.Output_Layer_Errors)
                            self.Hidden_Layer[-(e + 1)][-(f + 1)].update_weights(0, self.Learning_Tax)
                        else:
                            self.Hidden_Layer[-(e + 1)][-(f + 1)].get_error(0, self.Hidden_Layer_Errors[- (e + 1)])
                            self.Hidden_Layer[-(e + 1)][-(f + 1)].update_weights(0, self.Learning_Tax)
            j += 1
            print (self.Desired_Outputs)
            print (self.Real_Outputs)
```